# Why is my attribute value not changing using jQuery's .attr(x,y)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the value of the`onclick`attribute:

```
<span onclick="addPropertyToQuery(this)" tagId="${property.id}" class="half-padding half-margin tag">
```

The addPropertyToQuery() method looks something like this

```
function addPropertyToQuery(clicked){ 
     //
     // Other stuff
     //
    $(clicked).attr('onclick','removePropertyFromQuery(this)');
    alert($(clicked).attr('onclick'));
}
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong, what is most confusing is that the alert gives the correct value.

Comment: This is a common caveat of using inline event handlers. You're referencing the function before it exists.

Comment: Is that true if the function addPropertyToQuery() is not within the  $(document).ready(function() {});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `el.setAttribute('onclick', 'blah(this)')` works for me.

```
<button onclick="addMe(this)">addMe</button>
<script>
function addMe(el){
  el.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeMe(this)');
}
function removeMe(el){
  el.setAttribute('onclick', 'addMe(this)');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addPropertyToQuery(clicked){ 
 //
 // Other stuff
 //

    // Make sure you detach current click event handler
    $(clicked).unbind('click').click(function() { removePropertyFromQuery(this)});
}
```